# Package hyperxmp Error: hyperref must be loaded before hyperxmp. }

Tags: errors, compilation-error

I get a strange error message when using the command `\begin{itemize}`.
**At the same time, the text file is compiled on the *Overleaf* site without any problems**, but I can't work with the free version of *Overleaf* right now because of the huge compilation delay.

The error messages:

> Package hyperxmp Error: hyperref must be loaded before hyperxmp. }
>
> pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with
> scalable fonts. \begin{itemize}

```
Here is some text:
\begin{itemize}
    \item Item One.
    \item Item Two.
    \item Item Three.
\end{itemize}
```

I also checked `hyperxmp` file. The content of the section on the error message is as follows:

```
{%
  \PackageError{hyperxmp}%
    {hyperref must be loaded before hyperxmp}%
    {Recent versions of hyperref and the LaTeX kernel inhibit\MessageBreak
      hyperxmp's ability to hook into hyperref's internals unless\MessageBreak
      hyperref is loaded first.}
}
```

**PS.** I use ACM latex template for the journals.

Comment: make a small complete example that can be used for a test and show its log-file.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer , Please check if the information added in the question is enough.

Comment: no it is not enough. I asked for a *complete* example and a log file. A complete example starts with \documentclass and ends with \end{document}.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer , The article contains 41 pages ... I don't know which part I should put in the question ... so I just put the error message section.

Comment: Make a new test document. Copy your preamble, and a small hello world body (or your itemize9. Check if it shows the error. If yes remove as many packages as your can from your preamble (probably it is enough to keep the class and the microtype package).